Solving a Laplace Equation mixed boundary problem
I am struggling to solve the following boundary problem:
$$\Delta u=0,$$$$u(0,y)=0, u_x(1,y)=y^4$$$$u(x,0)=0,u_y(x,1)=x^4$$
for $(x,y)$ in the unit square. I was trying to use separation of variables but I can't find the form of $X(x)$ or $Y(y)$ so I cannot try the usual Fourier series approach.
Any help?

The answer to this similar problem may help you.
